# GD installed or not?

Tags: php, php-5.6, ubuntu-15.04

Ubuntu 15.04

```
php-v

PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:29:28) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

apt-get install php5-gd

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
php5-gd ya está en su versión más reciente.
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 7 no actualizados.
```

This means "PHP5-GD is installed in its latest version"

- A phpinfo() file doesn't show a GD section
- `php -m | grep gd` shows me nothing at all.

This is confusing for me, by a side it says I have the latest GD library version and the other side show me nothing at all about its presence.

Comment: Did you `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`? (i.e. restart apache)

Comment: Yes I did, with the same result.

Comment: What is the output of `php5 -m | grep -i gd` ?

Comment: The output of `php5 -m | grep -i gd` is nothing. The prompt again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache then you may need to enable the extension with something similar to:

```
a2enmod php5.6-gd
```

I hope it helps. If that doesn't work, have a look at your `php.ini` (you can find the right location with `phpinfo()`) and search for GD there, there is a chance you have to manually enable it for Apache in the correct INI file (not the CLI one).

Comment: When asking why not PHP 7, you may want to consider the timeline of this question -- the discussion had happened 3-4 years before PHP 7 was released.

Comment: Yes, I didn't see the date and was looking for unanswered questions. I will edit my answer which is still valid